# My page.php shows the index.php

Tags: php, themes, pages

Sorry for this simple question, I am very new to Wordpress.

I have a simple index.php that show a view of posts, just the images.

When I click on any post, it should send me to the full view of the post, which is defined in the page.php **This is the code of my page.php** is the same from this answer

```
<?php get_header() ?>

<?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Include the page content.
       the_content();

    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
?>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

It shows the index.php, but in the list of post, it shows just one element, the element that I clicked.

**this is my index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <body id="page-top">
    <!-- Navigation -->
      <?php get_template_part( 'navigation'); ?>
    <!-- Header -->
      <?php get_template_part( 'banner'); ?>
    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
      <?php get_template_part( 'portfolio'); ?>
    <!-- About Section -->
    <?php get_template_part( 'about'); ?>
    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <?php get_template_part( 'contact'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is the portafolio template, that show the list of all the posts:

```
  <?php 
  get_template_part('recent', 'posts');
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <!-- print the post link -->
    <a class="portfolio-item d-block mx-auto" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex position-absolute h-100 w-100">
        <div class="portfolio-item-caption-content my-auto w-100 text-center text-white">
          <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- print the post image -->
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-fluid')); ?>
    </a>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**This is how looks the index.php,** 
[image]

**and the page.php**
[image]

Comment: if you are viewing single posts of the `post` type, then `single.php` is the more specific template. `page.php` is for the `page` post type.